# flutter image picker image dissapear with no reason after several days

Tags: flutter

I add image picker package and successed to display image from gallery or camera. But after launch in prod I have serveral users with an issue.

When user select or take a picture, the image is display and save. After live test with user and after closing app and reload app, in same day I havn't issue. But after 1 or 2 days, user said me that image disappear...

here is the UI part

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child:  new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(File("${eventData.data10}")),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover
                      ))
              ),
            )
```

Here is my save path part

```
 File _image_picker;
 final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   setState(() {
     if (pickedFile != null) {
       _image_picker = File(pickedFile.path);
       prefs.setString('path_image_picker',pickedFile.path);
     } else {
       print('No image selected.');
     }
   });
 }
```

Here is my load path part

```
  load_image()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
     var  path_image_picker=prefs.getString('path_image_picker');
        _image_picker = File("$path_image_picker");
      
    });

  }
```

Comment: It's mean that image is deleted or not showing in your app ?

Comment: First the user select the image, second the path is saved with sharedpreference and the image is display with the selected path. This steps always work. But some time, and not for all users, the image isn’t display while the path is correctly loaded at the initstate

Comment: This is not normally can you tell me is the user phone android or ios ? I think you can write the checker method that after `setState()` check is image loaded if not loaded and path is true retry to loaded till image successfully loaded.

Comment: Currently I have only bad return from Android user. Strangely enough, after having retrieved the client logs, the path is retrieved, but displays something empty. 
It doesn't make sense ...

Comment: Did you know what is the user phone android version?And are you add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as an attribute to the <application> tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Yes for android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" I will demand the android version of the user concerned